# Remote desktop does not load css correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, remote-access

We have a application deployed on couple of servers. Some of them are deployed in our system and we have direct internet access to them. Others are deployed on a customer system and we do not have access to them. So we use remote desktop to connect to a customer machine which is connected via VPN to some other network where our application is running.

Problem seams to be that some html elements do not have their height set correctly. As far as we were able to see they have following CSS applied

```
display: flex;
height: 100%;
```

They would always have height of 0px and that is not expected. Their parent elements have their height set correctly.

On systems where we have direct access everything works as expected. Also if the customer connect directly to their system everything is fine.

My guess it that its somehow related to the remote access, but I have no idea how can that be. Any ideas/hints would be welcome.

Customer is using Chrome 64.0.3282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was related to a Chrome version, after updating to *Version 76.0.3809.100* everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding either

```
min-height: auto;
height: 0;
```